# Replace %26 in htaccess with %2526

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm importing a bunch of pages that have ampersands in the title, from Mediawiki. These are encoded as `%26`. Drupal, for various reasons, has decided to double encode the URL so it becomes `%2526`. I simply can't create the alaises within Drupal so I have to use htaccess.

I need `example.com/something_%26_else` to become `example.com/something_%2526_else`. This is what I have as my rule so far:

```
RewriteRule ^w/([^%26]+)\%26(.*)$ w/$1\%2526$2 [R=301]
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: in htaccess or within drupal? It does not work in Drupal.

Comment: You should solve the problem in Drupal, not by working around it. Find the file in Drupal processing URL's, and rewrite it.

Comment: @lekensteyn I spent the majority of the day trying to doing. The only solution required hacking the core in multiple parts and breaking about 1000 urls built on the previous way. As far as I can tell, Drupal response is live with it.

Comment: See also, the same question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/how-can-i-redirect-26-in-urls-to-2526-using-a-htaccess-rule

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'look-behind' mechanism with a `RewriteCond` and the `NEXT` flag to loop through the URI changing the %26 to %2526:

```
RewriteCond "\%(?<=25)26"
RewriteRule "^(w/.*)\%(?<=25)(26.*)" "$1\%25$2" [N]
```

Comment: The look-behind assertion is unnecessary in your example. It can never match because the previous character is always a `%`.

Comment: No, it isn't always `%`.  That's the point; it's not two encoded characters, it's one character whose encoding has been corrupted.

Comment: I'm talking about your regex, not the input. It begins with a `%`, therefore it must match that character, so when it then looks behind the next character it can never be a `5`.

Comment: I agree with @Walf, the regex `\%(?<=25)` will simply never match anything (`\%(?<=25\%)` could potentially match _something_, but the wrong _something_). (I wonder if you meant to use a negative lookahead, to avoid matching `%2526`, but that would also seem unnecessary?) However, there are other issues with these directives: The `RewriteCond` directive is missing the _TestString_ argument and the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is already %-decoded, so a literal `%26` will never match here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a *request* for `/<something>%26<something>` to `/<something>%2526<something>` then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule (.+)&(.+) /$1\%26$2 [R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path (ie. `&`, not `%26`). So you should simply specify `&` (ampersand) literally. Note that this will match a request for both `/something_%26_else` and `/something_&_else` (since `&` does not need to be encoded in the request).

The `%` (percent) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* needs to be backslash-escaped in order to represent a literal `%`, otherwise it's going to be seen as a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern*, and there isn't any, so `%2` would otherwise become an empty string!

By default, mod_rewrite automatically URL encodes the substitution URL, which is actually what we want in this instance: `%26` gets (doubly) encoded as `%2526`.

---

If you specifically need a looping construct, if for instance `%26` can occur more than once in the requested URL, then you can do something like the following instead:

```
# 1. Looping construct to replace all "&" (decoded %26)
RewriteRule (.+)&(.+) $1\%26$2 [N,E=REPLACED:yes]

# 2. Finally redirect. Substitution is only URL-encoded at this stage.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REPLACED} yes
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

---

See also my answer to the same question on the Pro Webmasters stack for more explanation and alternatives:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89074/1243